# Undefined variable: error in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have controller to input data to database and show error if duplicate data but i get message

> Undefined variable: error

```
$cek = DB::table('peserta')->where('email',$email)->count();
  if ($cek > 0 and count($error) > 0 ) {
    $pesan = [];
    $pesan['halu'] = 'danger';
    $pesan['message'] = 'Email anda sudah terdaftar';
  }
```

Comment: Where is `$error` coming from?

Comment: @tkausl if duplicate data get message error

Comment: You are not declaring what you want`$error` to be.

Answer (score 0):

your variable `$error` is undefined. Meaning, somewhere in your code, the variable `$error` is not assigned to any value, check your line 2 near `count($error)`.

Answer (score -2):

variable `$error` is undefined. Because you used $error,  but you are not declared `$error` before
"`if ($cek > 0 and count($error) > 0 )`"
this line. and this $error needs array type data. because, count() expect array type data.

## i think your code like :

```
$cek = DB::table('peserta')->where('email',$email)->count();
$error = your own errors array;
  if ($cek > 0 and count($error) > 0 ) {
    $pesan = [];
    $pesan['halu'] = 'danger';
    $pesan['message'] = 'Email anda sudah terdaftar';
  }
```